# D3 treemap - How to insert div into first level nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and want to make a treemap like this: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582#index.html

What I am going to do is to insert new div into parent nodes.

```
...
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, root) {
  var node = div.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
      .data(treemap.nodes)
    .enter().append("div")
// parent nodes have class name "first"
      .attr("class", function(d) { return d.children ? "node first" : "node"; })
      .call(position)
      .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? color(d.name) : null; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.children ? null : d.name; });

// my code
  var parents = d3.selectAll(".first")
     .data(treemap.value(function(d) { return d.size; }).nodes)  // ISSUE
     .enter().append("div")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    var value = this.value === "count"
        ? function() { return 1; }
        : function(d) { return d.size; };

    node
        .data(treemap.value(value).nodes)
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .call(position);
  });
});

...
```

But this doesn't work correctly.
**HOW CAN I UPDATE ONLY THE PAREENT NODES BY ADDING NEW DIV TO THEM?**
Could anybody help me please. Thanks a lot...

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.data()` and `.enter()` methods? Like so: `var parents = d3.selectAll(".first").append("div").text(function(d) { return d.name; });` Since the elements you wish to append to already exist, you shouldn't need a join or an `enter` selection.

Comment: I agree with @SeanEaster . These .data() and .enter() invocations don't make any sense to me. But maybe I don't see something...